# unable to see locations: [CLLocation]

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

info.plist file:

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>This project would like to know your location</string>

<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>location when app is in background</string>
```

As shown above, have added the key/value pairs for the info.plist

The problem i'm facing is that the first time i ran the app it prompted me for authorization, but, on subsequent runs the popup hasn't appeared.

second, I'm trying to print the locations from
`func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])` using the `print(location)` but nothing is printed.

in the debug options i have set location as "city bicycle ride"

The code i'm using is as follows.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate , CLLocationManagerDelegate {
@IBOutlet var map: MKMapView!

//use the locManager to get the users location

var locManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    locManager.delegate = self
    locManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    print(locations)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: i found a workaround for the location prompt. I reset the simulator and it worked. is there a way to fix it without resetting the simulator ?
The problem persists though..what i mean is that once i reset it , it prompts me once and never again till the next reset.

The locations aren't printing though...

Comment: What about calling `startUpdatingLocation()` ... ?

Comment: @MartinR Yes you're right, i had to call `startUpdatingLocation()`
thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS will ask only **once** for location authorization. If the user denies, he will have to change this in the device settings manually. If he agrees, you will be able to obtain the location until he blocks it in the device settings.

So this code:

```
locManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
```

will prompt a popup only **1 time**. The problem is that you probably forget to call:

```
locManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

You need to call this every time you want to start obtaining the location.

Comment: thanks ! that worked... so startUpdatingLocation() needs to be called.
currently the locations are printing, but the map is zoomed out to the country level. I'm guessing this can be fixed by introducing the Delta values, span and region? 

    `let span: MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, longDelta)

            let region: MKCoordinateRegion =   MKCoordinateRegionMake(locations, span)

            map.setRegion(region, animated: true)`

Haven't tried this yet, will update once i do. Thanks !!

Answer (score -1):

use this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
locationManager.delegate = self
locationManager.requestLocation()
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

Comment: Why request both `WhenInUseAuthorization` and `AlwaysAuthorization`? It looks like a copy-paste code...

Comment: Use Which you want to use.

Comment: But using both doesn't make any sense. `AlwaysAuthorization ` already covers (>) `WhenInUseAuthorization`.

Comment: Okay Noted !! Thanks (y) !!

Comment: If my understanding is correct requestAlwaysAuthorization() is best used when the app needs the location while the app runs in the background.

Comment: Exactly  !! if you want to use the location in background.